# Android Output Frame Coordinates

Tags: android, google-project-tango, tango

In the Google Tango doc for the [TangoSupport_fitPlaneModelNearPoint](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/support/reference/group/depth-support#group___depth_support_1ga84c3b49019bd1bdf0f087471eb8b268b) function the `intersection_point` value is given as a Vec3 in "Output Frame Coordinates"

When debugging this I find that the positive Z coordinate is always the distance away from the camera

I am assuming the right-hand rule so anyone have a source to confirm that this is what is meant for "Output Frame Coordinates"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting plane equation will be in the same reference frame that you pass the parameters in with.  That is the output coordinate space being referred to here.

So if you use StartOfService for your reference frame, then pass in base=StartOfService, target=DepthCamera for the point cloud position and base=StartOfService, target=ColorCamera or Device, depending on which one you are using for positioning the 3D camera.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I forgot I have the control of passing in the translation and orientation, I just always used the StartOfService.. but do you have a source for how it/when the device picks that StartOfService?

Answer (score -1):

Check the unit, the Tango device is output in "meter" and some of system unit is in "mm"